# AWS SWF Java: Activity returns value but promise never becomes ready

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have an unusual issue I think, and I'm looking for debugging help.

Problems:

1. Even though the AWS SWF Console shows the activity returned a valid response, the Flow Framework never marks the promise as ready! E.g. in the below code "activities.nextTask" is never scheduled for execution.
2. The only time "activities.nextTask" is scheduled for execution is if result is an empty list!

Workflow code:

```
@Override
public void myworkflow() {
    Promise<List<ValidationError>> result = activities.validate(input);
    handleValidationResult(result);

    Promise<Void> nextResult = activities.nextTask(input, result);
}

@Asynchronous
public void handleValidationResult(Promise<List<ValidationError>> result) {
   System.out.println("WHY ISN'T THIS BEING EXECUTED?");
}
```

and ValidationError looks like this (with lombok):

```
@Value
public class ValidationError {
    String message;
    boolean isRetryable;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that I verified two ValidationError instances with the same values are equal (using .equals()). Also worth noting that two lists of ValidationError with the same values are equal. I checked this incase the Flow replay relied on the equality of the results to be consistent. In my case they are consistent.

Comment: The code looks OK, but it could be that the workflow task is never executed after the activity completion. Make sure that the workflow task is started after the activity completion is reported. If it is started and then failed to produce correct result I would recommend running your code in the debugger using WorkflowReplayer described at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/troubleshooting.html.

Comment: The workflow task is scheduled and executed after the activity completes. I figured out the problem and posted the answer. Jackson needed a no-args constructor and I wasn't giving it one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ValidationError is missing a default constructor (i.e. no-args constructor).

Changed code to be:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ValidationError {
    ...
}
```

The passing of objects between the workflow and activities needs to be serialized and deserialized. SWF therefore requires a DataConverter to do this. The default DataConverter is the JsonDataConverter which is underpinned by Jackon. Jackson requires a no-arg constructor by default, but Lombok's @Value does not provide a no-args constructor. Hence Jackson wasn't able to deserialize the result from the activity. This explains why an empty list worked as expected, but a non-empty list of ValidationError didn't work as expected.

It turns out that the JsonDataConverter in SWF throws a DataConverterException when it encounters this issue, but somewhere in the SWF internals that exception is being swallowed. Debugging is difficult because when a failure occurs in the JsonDataConverter nothing is logged.

Adding a no-arg constructor resolves the issue.